# Install Python 3.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, installation

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I am trying to learn Python and I want to learn the latest version that is Python 3.3. But whenever I type "python --version" in my terminal it shows "Python 2.7.4". I have tried to install Python 3.3 using these commands  -

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev
$ wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2

$ tar jxf ./Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2

$ cd ./Python-3.3.0

$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3

$ make && sudo make install
```

I believe I have been successful but it still shows "Python 2.7.4". Then I tried this other command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3.3
```

But it still shows that I am using Python 2.7.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Ubuntu, then I'm pretty sure python3 already comes installed. You can type python and hit tab in Bash. Python 3 should come up, no need to go through configure, make, make install.

Comment: Np, don't forget to select an answer as the chosen correct one.

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get` installs python 3 as `python3`.

```
~$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want access to Python 3.3 (or any other version) you can download it at http://www.python.org/download/

I hope this helps,
Jake Nixon